# Add a class to a <div> at any point in the viewport - not just when it appears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to be able to add a class to an element such as a `<div>` once it's reached any point of the viewport based on my choosing.

It would be great to set this as a percentage value - so the top of the viewport would be 0, the middle 50% and so on.

I've been using the following function to detect when an element appears in the viewport:

```
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};
```

https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/

But more control would be ideal. Is it possible to do this in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `isInViewport` function in such a way that it accepts 2 more arguments which describe the top and left thresholds:

```
var isInViewport = function (elem, yThreshold, xThreshold) {
  var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <= yThreshold && // <-- use here
    bounding.right <= xThreshold     // <-- and here
  );
};
```

And then use it like so:

```
var myEl = document.querySelector('#my-element-id');

isInViewport(myEl, window.innerHeight * 0.5, window.innerWidth);
```